# Warum braucht man das Wort „gewesen“?

Tags: grammaticality, subjunctive, passive

Ich habe schon öfter gehört die folgenden Sätze:

> Das wäre meine nächste Frage gewesen.

Warum braucht man da das Wort „gewesen“? Meines Wissens handelt es sich um einen Konjunktiv 2 in der Aktivform der Gegenwart. Warum könnte man nicht einfach

> Das wäre meine nächste Frage

sagen?

Ein anderer Satz, jedoch in der Passivform, mit dem ich das ähnliche Problem habe ist auch:

> Das Spiel soll von vielen Bugs geplagt gewesen sein.

Warum braucht man da „gewesen“?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Gewesen* ist das Partizip II von *sein* und wird benötigt, um das Perfekt von *sein* zu bilden.

> Er **ist** traurig **gewesen**.

Manchmal kann man das Präteritum gebrauchen, um über Vergangenes zu sprechen.

> Er **war** traurig.

Es gibt jedoch einige Kontexte, in denen **auf dem Perfekt basierende Formen** unverzichtbar sind. Dann wird das Partizip II benötigt.

1. Infinitiv Perfekt.

> Er **muss** sehr traurig **gewesen sein**.
>   Er **scheint** sehr traurig **gewesen zu sein**.

2. Plusquamperfekt.

> In der Therapie lernte er, warum er als Teenager so traurig **gewesen war**.

3. Konjunktive I und II der Vergangenheit.

> Man sagt, er **sei** traurig **gewesen**.
>   Er sieht so aus, als ob er traurig **gewesen wäre**.

Answer (score 4):

In Deinen Beispielen wird *gewesen* dafür verwendet um auszudrücken, dass der beschriebene Umstand / Sachverhalt gegenwärtig nicht mehr zutreffend ist.

> Warum könnte man nicht einfach
>
> > Das wäre meine nächste Frage
>
> sagen?

Das erwartet weiterhin eine Antwort auf die Frage. Hingegen impliziert

> > Das wäre meine nächste Frage gewesen

dass die Frage bereits beantwortet wurde, ohne sie explizit zu stellen.

> Ein anderer Satz, jedoch in der Passivform, mit dem ich das ähnliche
>   Problem habe ist auch:
>
> > Das Spiel soll von vielen Bugs geplagt gewesen sein.
>
> Warum braucht man da „gewesen“?

Hier impliziert *gewesen*, dass diese Bugs mittlerweile behoben wurden.

Answer (score 2):

"Gewesen" bedeutet, dass dies in der Vergangenheit so war. Über die Gegenwart wird dabei *technisch* gesehen nichts ausgesagt, es ist aber üblicherweise stark impliziert, dass der besprochene Sachverhalt gegenwärtig nicht mehr zutrifft.

> Das wäre meine nächste Frage gewesen.

In der Situation hat sich die Frage erledigt. Entweder, weil sie bereits beantwortet wurde, oder weil sie jemand anders bereits gestellt hat.

> Das Spiel soll von vielen Bugs geplagt gewesen sein.

Das Spiel hatte viele Bugs in der Vergangenheit. Es ist zu erwarten, dass das Spiel gegenwärtig durch Patches & Updates keine Bugs mehr hat (oder zumindest deutlich weniger). Lässt man das "gewesen" weg, so ist die Aussage, dass das Spiel aktuell von vielen Bugs geplagt sein soll - was ein völlig anderer Sachverhalt ist.

"Gewesen" bedeutet also buchstäblich, das etwas in der Vergangenheit so gewesen ist (und eine häufig angenommene Implikation ist, das dies aktuell nicht mehr der Fall ist).